# Python Beautiful soup tag for table td

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Python Beautiful soup tag for table td

```
  <td class="result" valign="top" colspan="3">
```

At the moment, the following does not work:

```
for header in soup('table', 'td .result'):
```

Getting error:

```
HTMLParser.HTMLParseError: malformed start tag
```

Comment: Your soup is composed of an entire html page, or just your td line ?

Comment: its entire page, with a list of td's

Answer (score 1):

As noted on their [website](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/3.1-problems.html), HTMLParser is [quite](http://groups.google.com/group/beautifulsoup/browse_thread/thread/2f7c284eeecd3068/d5a7540620538d14?pli=1) [fragile](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/35418-urllib2-problems-webserver). You should use SGMLParser instead, as it's more robust against malformed HTML.

Unfortunately, Python 3.0 has removed SGMLParser from the standard library. See the links above for suggested workarounds, such as using [html5lib](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/).